# Why does this compile?

Tags: java, exception, casting

I was taken aback earlier today when debugging some code to find that something like the following does not throw a compile-time exception:

```
 public Test () { 
     HashMap map = (HashMap) getList(); 
 }

 private List getList(){
     return new ArrayList();
 }
```

As you can imagine, a `ClassCastException` is thrown at runtime, but can someone explain why the casting of a `List` to a `HashMap` is considered legal at compile time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19895304/classcastexception-vs-cannot-cast-compilation-error/37190861#37190861

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Because conceivably `getList()` could be returning a subclass of `HashMap` which also implements `List`. Unlikely, yes, but possible, and therefore compilable.

Comment: +1: An explicit cast is basically a situation where the programmer is telling the compiler "I know what I'm doing, so do it my way" - if the compiler doesn't know that you're really really wrong, it will go your way.  Well, that's one way that it was explained to me.

Comment: Yeah, the compiler should complain if you replace `List` with `ArrayList`.

Comment: @weiji: That's only true to some extent, and far less true than it was in C or C++. The java compiler will only give you so much rope, and if A cannot possibly be an instance of B, it will not compile.

Comment: Thanks.  Looking at the JLS (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.5), it looks obvious after reading your explanation.  It follows that final classes like `String` cannot be cast at compile-time, as there cannot potentially be a subclass which would implement `List`.

Answer (score 17):

For one thing List is an interface. There is no reason why there couldn't exist a subclass of HashMap which also implements the List interface. In this situation it would be perfectly valid.