# ClassCastException vs. "cannot cast" compilation error

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, classcastexception

Studying for my OCA Java SE 7 Programmer I exam, so newbie question. I have an example question I do not understand. The following code compiles, but gives a ClassCastException at runtime:

```
interface Roamable {
}

class Phone {
}

public class Tablet extends Phone implements Roamable {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Roamable var = (Roamable) new Phone();
    }
}
```

When I change `Roamable var = (Roamable) new Phone();` into `Roamable var = (Roamable) new String();` I get a compilation error right away.

Two questions:

1. Why does the code above compile at all? Phone seems unrelated to Roamable to me?
2. Why does the code compile with `new Phone()`, but doesn't it compile with `new String()`?

Comment: The compiler knows that String is `final` and hence there's no way that a subclass of String could be Roamable.

Comment: This is a very nice question blocking my head for long time :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why does the code above compile at all? Phone seems unrelated to
>   Roamable to me?

yes because `Roamable` is an interface it might cause a Run-time exception but not compile time exception, because even if `Phone` doesn't implement `Roamable`, a subclass of `Phone` might, hence the compiler has no way to know it but at the Run time.

It is already defined in java language specification. [**Check out my answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19824941/why-does-it-compile-when-casting-to-an-unrelated-interface/19825137#19825137).

> Why does the code compile with new Phone(), but doesn't it compile
>   with new String()?

Because `class String` is declared as `public final class` in `java.lang` package. As specified in [**`jls 8.1.1.2 final class`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.2) section: a class declared as `final` can't  be extended and hence it won't have any subclass. So, the compiler already knows that `String` can't be extended: hence no subclass's existence is possible to implement *interface* `Roamable`

**Edit: (With response to your below comment)**

Let us assume that `B` is a subclass of `A` which implements an interface `T`.

Now an statement :

```
   T t = (T)new A();
```

is essentially same as:

```
   A aObj = new A() ;
   T t = (T)aObj ; // a run-time exception happen
```

before running into conclusion, let us do the same thing with an object of `B`:

```
   A aObj = new B();
   T t = (T)aObj; // no exception happen.
```

so, the real reason with super class and sub class here is the reference. The `aObj` class in this second code example is also an instance of class `A` but it is also an instance of class `B` which has implemented `T`.

Comment: But the code in my example says to make a new `Phone`, not an object of some other class that might extend `Phone` and implement `Roamable`. I don't see why the compiler cares about a possibly existing subclass here?

Comment: @luukburger, updated the answer. Check with the example provided. Assume class `A` as your `Phone` class

Comment: Hmmm... Thanks for your help. So the compiler says: `new Phone()` will hand me _an object of type `Phone`_. Maybe really a `Phone`, maybe a `Phone2` that implements Roamable. It doesn't see that no `Phone2` class exists thus that that assumption is wrong...?

Comment: The existence of class `Phone2` will be known at none but run-time. :)
Don't forget to check this site's [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about). Welcome to stack overflow

Answer (score 4):

String is final so there is no way it can be cast to a Roamable.

Comment: So I could cast an object of any non-final class into a Roamable, as far as the compiler is concerned?

Comment: @luukburger Yes, because the compiler does not know if a subclass of the casting type implements Roamable. If the class is final, no such subclass can exist.

Comment: Also if you try casting to class (assume Roamable is class) will results in “cannot cast” compilation error

Comment: Since java supports single inheritance for class which can be identified at compile time, but interface can be implemented at any sub class level (multiple inheritance) compiler cant identify.

Answer (score 1):

The code compiles because the compiler lets you cast to anything. It is an explicit action by the programmer, and the compiler assumes you have assessed the risks and taken the appropriate precautions.

`String` is not an instance of `Roamable`, so you cannot assign an instance of `String` to a `Roamable` reference. And that can be determined at compile time, so it fails.

Comment: But `Phone` is also not an instance of `Roamable`?

Comment: Not as you have it. To do that, you need `class Phone implements Roamable`. And then `Tablet` could just extend `Phone`.

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant was: both String and Phone are (in the code above) not an instance of Roamable, but still `new String()` gives a compilation error and `new Phone()` doesn't...

Comment: @luukburger, check out my answer. I would write here but it will rather take space

Answer (score 1):

`new Phone()` evals into class `Phone`, which *could* be an extension of `Phone` that implements `Roamable` (as far as the compiler is concerned).

If you made Phone a `final` class (like String), you will get the compiler error.

Comment: In particular, `Tablet` is an existing subclass of `Phone` that implements `Roamable.` If Phone was `final`, it'd be a trick to get the class `Tablet` to compile at all :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice Tablet was extending Phone... not much point since it's never instantiated and just used for the main entry point

Answer (score 0):

A good question. `new Phone()` is definitely not any subclass of `Phone`. However that information is lost, javac sees a `Phone` type there, not the *exact* `Phone` type.

Relevant spec: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5.1

> If S is a final class (§8.1.1), then S must implement T,

The spec can be amended with

> If the expression is a Class Instance Creation Expression (§15.9), the type of the expression must be a subtype of T.

Answer (score 0):

First read about [Explicit and Implicit type casting](http://www.javainterviewpoint.com/type-casting-java-implicit-explicit-casting/) by java. 
From that user is responsible for explicit casting when narrowing down the object relationship to say that user knows and fine with they loose some precision because of this. However still compiler can detect some explicit wrong casting and throw `CE: Type mismatch error` at some point. Beyond that point it is up to runtime `ClassCastException` to deal with it.

> Compiler can detect the following cases of explicit casting.

```
class A {}
class B {}

A a = (A) new B(); //CE: Type mismatch: cannot convert from B to A
B b = (B) new A(); //compilation error (CE)
```

---

```
interface I {}
final class A {}
I i = (I) new A();  //compilation error
```

---

> Compiler can not detect the following cases of explicit casting.

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
A a = (A) new B(); //Fine
B b = (B) new A(); //Runtime error; because compile time;
                   //compiler wont be able to tell the reference is instance of A or B.
                   //means this is something like below. <BR>
B b = (B) (A) new A();
```

---

Any Object can be caste to any interface without compilation error.

```
interface I {}
class A {}
class B extends A implements I{}

I i = (I) new A();  //Runtime error
I i = (I) new B();  //Fine
```

---

[Why does this compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495308/why-does-this-compile)

Reference of interfaces can castes to any object without compilation error.

```
interface I {}
class A implements I {}
class B {}

B b = (B) getI();     //Runtime error
OR 
B b = (B)(I)new A();  //Runtime error

public I getI() {
 return new A();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think no need too many words. Simply kindly consider the following example by keeping in mind that ***a superior reference can be a pointer to its one of subclasses.***

```
class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      
     class x {}
     interface z {}
     class y extends x implements z {}

     x xx = new x();
     // var q = (z)xx; // class cast exception
     xx = (new y()); // xx is kinda superior ref-type of "class y" right? It can point it.
     var qq = (z)xx;
    }
}
```

If we restrain it, how can the reference refer to the object after the correct casting? (at the last line)